# cant hide data that was dynamically added

Tags: javascript, hide, jquery

this is the function to hide the data

```
$(".dispatch_pedido").live('click', function(){

    var res = this.id.split("_");

    var id = res[1];

    $("#"+id).hide();
});
```

this code only works on the data that was initially added but not the data added by ajax.

Comment: You should use a more recent version of jQuery. Having a so old version of a library which evolves to adapt to new versions of browsers makes no sense.

Comment: is a WEB APP programmed 4 years ago, if I update jquery the LIVE function will stop working on other parts of the site... @dystroy

Comment: `live` is deprecated since version 1.7 use `on` instead.

Comment: need more details, can you arrange a testcase on jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0):

When you use ajax to add new element to the DOM, you need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) so the event can bind to that newly added element:

```
$(document).on('click', '.dispatch_pedido' , function(){

});
```

Also, `live` is deprecated as of jQuery version `1.7` , you should use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) instead.

---

You can use [**delegate()**](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead of `on()` in old version of jQuery:

```
$(document).delegate( ".dispatch_pedido", "click", function() {
    // Your code here  
});
```

Comment: Cant update jquery everything build on this web app is build with live (4 year old application), I knew a way of using the selectors needed but i forgot about it.

Comment: @Felix Click functions is working with the code I provided the problem is the hide() functions doesnt, with delegate is the same thing click works hide doesnt.

Comment: @bmacuer what is the result of your `id`? Can you `console.log(id)` and see the result?

Comment: @Felix I was appending the id incorrectly for the table tr.id, thats why hide() wasnt working. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your syntax is not correct. Checkout the below code.

```
$(".dispatch_pedido").live('click', function(){

    var res = $(this).attr("id").split("_");

    var id = res[1];

    $("#"+id).hide();
});
```